# Why is Typescript telling me " 'offset' does not exist in type 'UseScrollOptions' "?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, framer-motion

I am building a React website with NextJS 13, Typescript, and Framer Motion. I have the following code, basically copied and pasted from the Framer docs:

`const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({ target: targetRef, container: containerRef, offset: ['start end', 'end end'], });`

Typescript is underlining 'offset' and telling me

```
'offset' does not exist in type 'UseScrollOptions'
```

How could type **offset** not exist in UseScrollOptions when the docs tell you that's how to do it? I've used this method of creating animations with scroll before and I've never received this error. What am I doing wrong?

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Framer motion (I am using 10.13). I even tried rolling back to 10.12 and it gave me the same answer. I have no idea how to fix this when I am copying and pasting from the docs and it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the same issue with framer-motion 10.13. As pointed out in the other answer, it looks like the current type files actually don't provide the `offset` field. O.o

Types: [UseScrollOptions](https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/main/packages/framer-motion/src/value/use-scroll.ts#L10), extends [ScrollOptions](https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/main/packages/framer-motion/src/render/dom/scroll/types.ts#L3).

Downgrading to version 10.12.18 was the only solution I found:

```
npm install framer-motion@10.12.18
```

Note: In my scenario, I had `"framer-motion": "^10.12.18"` (with caret) in my package.json which allowed the installation of 10.13. To show the currently installed version use `npm list`.

Comment: I upvoted this answer not because it solves the problem but because it helps silence the error. Looks like a problem with the new version of Framer Motion and Typescript. Hopefully, we will get a fix soon

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, it seems like it has not been defined as a type in the 'framer-motion' package

Here the interface UseScrollOptions is defined and it does not define a type for 'offset': line 10
https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/main/packages/framer-motion/src/value/use-scroll.ts

And neither does ScrollOptions that it extends: line 3
https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/main/packages/framer-motion/src/render/dom/scroll/types.ts

Possible solution would be to create a PR to their repo with a fix.

Answer (score -1):

You must have defined a type called UseScrollOptions, which values ​​are defined with their own types: target: targetRef, container: containerRef, but you did not define the offset in this type.

interface UseScrollOptions {
target: TTarget,
container: type,
offset: TOffset,
}

enum TOffset  { 'start end', 'end end'}

type TTarget {
enum1: type1,
enum2: type1
enum3: type1
enum4: type1
}

Comment: I have not defined a type called UseScrollOptions. That type is defined by Framer Motion. Here is the snippet from Framer's type.d.ts file:

interface UseScrollOptions extends Omit<ScrollOptions, "container" | "target"> {
    container?: RefObject$1<HTMLElement>;
    target?: RefObject$1<HTMLElement>;
    layoutEffect?: boolean;
}
declare function useScroll({ container, target, layoutEffect, ...options }?: UseScrollOptions): {
    scrollX: MotionValue<number>;
    scrollY: MotionValue<number>;
    scrollXProgress: MotionValue<number>;
    scrollYProgress: MotionValue<number>;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).